# Why does a simple update cursor take so much time?

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

This script is running for the past 10 minutes. It is operating on a table with only 10 records. What is wrong with the script?

```
declare
  cursor cus is 
  select * from customers
  for update of salary;
begin
  for i in cus
  loop
    update customers
    set salary = salary * 0.15
    where current of cus;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: And it is still running! There is something grossly wrong with this thing! ;)

Comment: Because of many things: 1. you hit the target table many times (at least twice when you fetch a row and when you update it - `update` statement always has a "read" part); 2. Instead of using a single simple `update` statement you've placed it in a PL/SQL `for` loop statement, where it'd be executed(send to the SQL engine) as many times as many rows your `customers` table has. So, in this situation, there is absolutely no need to use PL/SQL. But for the table with only 10 records, 10 minutes is a lot of time. Looks like the table was locked before you ran your script.

Comment: Thanks @NicholasKrasnov - The idea was not to use update in this particular situation. Just trying to figure out what all can be done using pl/sql blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a simple cursor but I don't use the "where current of", rather I match on a key.

update customers
set salary = i.salary *.15
where cus_key = i.cus_key